# Glow effect shader works on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: three.js, glsl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm currently working on a personal project to generate a planet using procedural methods. The problem is that I am trying to achieve a glow effect using glsl. The intended effect works for desktop but not for mobile. 
The following link illustrate the problem:

Intended Effect

[image]

iPhone6S result

[image]

The planet are composed as follows: Four `IcosahedronBufferGeometry` meshes composing earth, water, cloud and glow effect. I have tried disabling glow effect, then it works as intended for mobile. Therefore, the conclusion is that the problem lies within the glow effect.

Here are the code for the glow effect (fragment and vertex shader):

**Vertex shader**:

```
varying float intensity;

void main() {
  /* Calculates dot product of the view vector (cameraPosition) and the normal */
  /* High value exponent = less intense since dot product is always less than 1 */
  vec3 vNormal = vec3(modelMatrix * vec4(normal, 0.0));
  intensity = pow(0.2 - dot(normalize(cameraPosition), vNormal), 2.8);

  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
}
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
varying float intensity;

void main() {
  vec3 glow = vec3(255.0/255.0, 255.0/255.0, 255.0/255.0) * intensity;
  gl_FragColor = vec4( glow, 1.0);
}
```

**THREE.js Code**

```js
var glowMaterial, glowObj, glowUniforms, sUniforms;
sUniforms = sharedUniforms();

/* Uniforms */
glowUniforms = {
    lightPos: {
        type: sUniforms["lightPos"].type,
        value: sUniforms["lightPos"].value,
    }
};

/* Material */
glowMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: THREE.UniformsUtils.merge([
        THREE.UniformsLib["ambient"],
        THREE.UniformsLib["lights"],
        glowUniforms
    ]),
    vertexShader: glow_vert,
    fragmentShader: glow_frag,
    lights: true,
    side: THREE.FrontSide,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    transparent: true
});

/* Add object to scene */
glowObj = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.IcosahedronBufferGeometry(35, 4), glowMaterial);
scene.add(glowObj);
```

There are no error/warning messages in the console both for desktop and mobile using remote web inspector. As previously shown, it seems for mobile, the glow is plain white meanwhile for desktop, the intensity/color/opactiy of the material based on the value of the dot product in vertex shader works.

Comment: just a guess. pow(f, e) negativ f dont work.

Comment: i would test it with glow=vec3(1) * magicnr. when this also fails, their are some bugs known to occur on specific mobiles. so on what mobile you run your test (?).

Comment: @nabr I tried with glow=vec3(1.0) * intensity, it also fails. I have an iPhone 6s.

Comment: @dd321 is possible for you to provide a live example (codepen or jsfiddle) of this problem?

Comment: @ScieCode Here is a live-demo of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/3pnqhd7m/1/
Notice the vertex shader line: `  intensity = pow(0.1 - dot(normalize(cameraPosition), vNormal), 2.8);`. If we increase the exponent of the pow function i.e 2.8 = less intensity. I also noticed that if I don't subtract the value with the result from the dot product, it works but the glow is centered in the middle of the planet and is thus not the desired effect I want.

Comment: I was able to make it work correctly by replacing intensity with `pow( 1.0 - dot(normalize(cameraPosition), normalize(vNormal)), 2.8);`.

Comment: You actually need to normalize the normal vector and guarantee the `pow` function isn't taking negative values. [codepen](https://codepen.io/sciecode/full/WVJQLN)

Comment: @ScieCode This is weird, the reason I subtract the result of the dot product with a value LESS than 1.0, say 0.2, is because I want the glow to be faded, see the first image. If I subtract with 1.0, I would get outlines around the sphere but it would then work for mobile.

Comment: @dd321 I thought you wanted the outline glow, if you want the opposite. Just set the intensity to be equal the dot product, instead of `1.0 - dot`.

Comment: Good question,why flagging it for closing? @ScieCode care to put an answer?